# insert post data into mongoDB using Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am very new to node JS and mongo.

I am working on a personal website that stores a user's information in my database.

For simplicity, let's say I have the following form in jade...

```
form(class="inputs", action="/login", method="post")
    input(type="text", name="email",class="form-control", id="emailLogin", placeholder="Queen's Email")
```

I already set up a database, and I was able to connect to it using the following javascript...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/user');
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function() {
    // Create your schemas and models here.
});
```

I want to store the input from `email` for every user that registers using the form above.

I am guessing I would first have to create a schema, which would probably look like this, but I'm not sure...

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String
});
//I think I have to create a model too?
```

And to get POST data I think I would need some code that looks like this...

```
app.post('/login', function(request, response){
//I am not sure what to put inside
});
```

My question is, can someone show me how to implement all these together so that every time a user registers with their email, it is saved in the database. It is very hard to research this, and have tried and failed many times.

**EDIT**

Here is my `index.js` file...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'QChat' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Also, here is another file in my `routes` directory called `users.js`, I'm not sure what its purpose is...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Where is `post()` method?

Comment: @zangw I think I see what you mean, should a post method be included inside the my index file? In that case, I do not have one.

Comment: To be more precisely, it is better to include `post(''/login)` to `use.js`, I guess this file is just for url routing for users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some sample codes, hope it could help you.

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    email: String
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

app.post('/login', function(request, response){
    var u = new User({
        email: request.body.name
    });

    u.save(function(err) {
        if (err)
           throw err;
        else 
           console.log('save user successfully...');
    });
});
```

Also to parse the post url correctly, [express](http://expressjs.com/) could be used here, sample codes as below.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
```

Comment: This looks good, but I still cannot get it to work. When I submit the form, nothing gets saved in the db

Comment: I'm thinking your code, should work, the reason its not working for me is probably the `404 Not Found` that I keep getting when I submit a form

Comment: @Bolboa, what is your post url?

Comment: Im not exactly sure, here, I'll edit my answer to include my index.js file. Webstorm helped complete much of my code so I am having trouble understanding it all.

Comment: I see, I'm not sure where/how to include the post method, but seeing as that is a separate question, I'll still give you best answer. But I would appreciate if you could help resolve the 404 issue

Comment: @Bolboa, maybe you could share your codes with one repository in github, I can check it in this way... As you mentioned, it would be another issue, and you could ask another question in here...

Answer (score 1):

user.model.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , Schema = mongoose.Schema
    , Q = require('q')
    ;

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
})

UserSchema.methods.Save = function() {
    return Q.ninvoke(this, 'save');
}

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

user.controller.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    , User = mongoose.model('User')
    ;

app.post('/create', function(request, response){
   var user = new User();
   user.email = request.body.email;

    return user.Save().then(function(users) {
        // some code if save succeed
    }, function(err){
        // some code if save failed
    });
});
```